# How can I add a custom Javascript snippet to display my feedback in footer?

Tags: plugins, customization, javascript, content

I have the following Javascript snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="\<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.auctionnudge.com/feed/feedback/js/theme/profile_table/limit/6/lang/english/UserID/stockmustgo/siteid/3"></script><div id="auction-nudge-feedback" class="auction-nudge"></div>
```

Which should dynamically display my eBay feedback like this:

https://gyazo.com/1ddc1e3f2ca21c91897a986a01654df8

How can I add this to my wordpress site? I tried installing the ' Header and Footer Scripts ' plugin to no avail. I'm sure it's simple but I'm a beginner when it comes to anything web dev related.

It doesn't need to be displayed in the footer. It can be within the body. I've asked around and I couldn't find anyone that could help so I thought I'd try here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a HTML Widget to your footer and place the content in there.

WordPress Admin > Appearance > Widgets.

I've just tested with the following JavaScript snippet and this works as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('Hello World')
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, isn't displaying anything. Maybe it's a problem with the script. I think I read somewhere that Wordpress doesn't like displaying dynamic scripted content?

Comment: Are you using WordPress .com or .org?

Comment: Hi, as far as I'm aware I'm using .org (I am using SiteGround to host). I think .com is for sites that are hosted by Wordpress so I must be using .org. Here is the site: https://moddedgamesaves.com/

Comment: Did you try the snippet I posted to see if it would work for you? I generated the snippet using this site: https://www.auctionnudge.com/tools/feedback/preview#middle

Comment: No. But looking at it, it's not valid syntax. Looks like you need to get to grips with some basics around JavaScript syntax, https://www.w3schools.com/js/.

Comment: That'll be why then. Cheers. I'll take a look. I assumed that it would be syntactically correct considering it was machine-generated.